# Google App Engine __main__ module

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm building a data seeder module that looks for all models using introspection and the `inspect` module. I index the models I found by a string looking like `module.model_name` because there might be more modules with the same name in different modules.

The problem is that `module` sometimes is indeed the right module name, but sometimes it's `__main__`, probably because that specific module was the first one that was called to handle a URL after an instance was started. Is there anyway I can avoid this, perhaps by forcing a specific module to always be `__main__`?

This problems gets worse when I have multiple instances running at once because I also get inconsistent data between instances, each having a different `__main__` module.

Thanks

Comment: What on earth is a "data seeder"?

Comment: A data seeder is a module that provides seed data. Perhaps it's not the best name, I haven't really seen it on the internets, but hey, that's what it does

Comment: You mean sample data, such as for testing? Or fuzzing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each `script` entry in your `app.yaml` will be executed as a `__main__` module. If you only want a single `__main__` then you need to run everything through a single entry-point and map everything via a single `WSGIApplication` instance.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but what you said seems correct. I'm accepting your answer but still looking for better ways. I can't really provide a single `script` since some of those are third-party libraries.

Comment: @sttwister FWIW, only one module will be called `__main__` at any one time - the one that was called for this request. If your code is always called by the same module, you should know what that one is. If not, there are various hacks you could use to figure out what it is, such as examining the stack.